# HTML, CSS image positioning

Tags: html, css

From Cpanel preview, images are arranged horizontally.

But when I publish the actual website, the images are arranged vertically.

The HTML Code is this

```html
<p dir="ltr">
  <strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
   <span style="font-size:14px">
    <a href="https://www.dur.ac.uk/dece/" target="_blank">
     <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/durham_logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://bitbots.pk/about" target="_blank">
     <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/bit-bots-logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.goread.pk/" target="_blank">
     <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/goread-logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
    </a>
    <a href="https://deafreach.com/" target="_blank">
     <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/deaf-reach-logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
    </a>
   </span>
  </span>
 </strong>
  <br/>
</p>
```

I want the website to have images side-by-side horizontally. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all your codes instruction is totally bad, You need to use `display: inline-block` to let parents controll their children easily. as you can see in the snippet you can find how i used `display` and `max-width` and also never use limited width for `img` tags sometime's decrease's your image quality.
if you want to learn about side-by-side things take a look at [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp)

```css
a {
display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 120px;
margin-right: 30px;
  
}

a:last-child {

margin-right: 0;
}

img {

width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<p dir="ltr">
 <strong>
  <span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">
   <span style="font-size:14px">
<a href="https://www.dur.ac.uk/dece/" target="_blank">
 <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/durham_logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
</a>
<a href="https://bitbots.pk/about" target="_blank">
 <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/bit-bots-logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
</a>
<a href="https://www.goread.pk/" target="_blank">
 <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/goread-logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
</a>
<a href="https://deafreach.com/" target="_blank">
 <img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/deaf-reach-logo.png" style="height:30%; width:30%"/>
</a>
   </span>
  </span>
 </strong>
 <br/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but it was resolved using max-width not the percentage. Try it.

Comment: I tried this:

<img alt="" src="https://edtechworx.s3.amazonaws.com/ckuploads/2020/06/20/durham_logo.png" style="height:30%; max-width:100px" />

It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code snippet, only the 4th image is in the next line and that is because the images' width crosses the window size which makes the last image move down to the second line. Each image is of 30% width, obviously, you cannot accommodate all the images in one row.

Comment: But when I publish actual website, all images starts a new line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUWyo.jpg